# Wordpress pagination not working with filters

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I have a problem with wordpress pagination. I have a query, which generates lists of posts:

```
 $args = array('post_type' => 'post', 'post__in' => $wynik, 'cat' => 10,'paged' => $paged);
 $the_query=new WP_Query( $args );
```

Where `$wynik` is an array with posts id. This array is created based on filters, using which user can filter posts.

The pagination works fine, when no filters are  used, so all posts from the query are displayed. But when I use some filters and want to display for example posts with specific values in custom fields, pagination works weird. My query works fine, I can display posts with specific values in custom fields, but pagination still thinks that query is full, so even if I have for example only 5 results, pagination is still there and when I click second page it takes me to second page of posts and loses my filters.

It is all on category page. My filters form looks like this (it is part of it):

```
 <form role="form" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>?cat=10" method="post" id="formFiltr">
                            <div class="filter" id="skipfilter">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="large-18 columns">
                                            <h3>Użyj filtrów, aby szybko odnaleźć interesujący Cię nabór:</h3>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="large-18 columns">
                        <span style="line-height: 30px; display: block;" class="filter-title">Pokaż według</span>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="large-18 columns">
                                    <label for="wszystkie-nabory" title="Zaznacz, aby wyświetlić tylko ogłoszenia o naborach wniosków">
                                        <input type="radio" value="4" onchange="" id="wszystkie-nabory" name="ogloszenie" onclick="this.form.submit();" <?php if (($_POST['ogloszenie']) == 4) echo 'checked';?>>
                                        Ogłoszenia o naborach wniosków
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="large-18 columns">
                                    <label for="tylko-wyniki">
                                        <input type="radio" value="5" onchange="" id="tylko-wyniki" title="Zaznacz, aby wyświetlić tylko wyniki naborów wniosków" name="ogloszenie" onclick="this.form.submit();" <?php if (($_POST['ogloszenie']) == 5) echo 'checked';?>>
                                        Tylko wyniki naborów wniosków
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            <div class="row">              
                            <div class="large-18 small-9 columns">
                                <label class="filter-title" for="filter_Temat">Temat</label>
                                    <?php 
                                    $wynikiQS = get_custom('wnioski_tematy');
                                    $wynikiQS = explode('|',$wynikiQS);

                                    ?>
                                    <select class="help MIRFiszkaFiltryTematNaboru" onchange="this.form.submit();" id="filter_Temat" name="temat">
                                        <option style="padding-left:15px;" value=""> Wszystkie </option>
                                        <?php  foreach ( $wynikiQS as $wynikQS ) {
                                            $wynikQS = (string)$wynikQS;
                                            if (($_POST['temat']) == $wynikQS) echo '<option value="'.$wynikQS.'" class="filterItem" selected>'.$wynikQS.'</option>';
                                            else echo '<option value="'.$wynikQS.'" class="filterItem">'.$wynikQS.'</option>';
                                        } ?>
                                    </select>

                            </div>
                            <div class="large-18 small-9 columns">
                                <label class="filter-title" for="filter_Wojewodztwo">Priorytet</label>
                                <?php 
                                    $wynikiQS1 = get_custom('wnioski_priorytety');
                                    $wynikiQS1 = explode('|',$wynikiQS1);
                                    ?>
                                    <select class="help MIRFiltryWojewodztwo"  onchange="this.form.submit();" id="filter_Wojewodztwo" name="priorytet">
                                        <option style="padding-left:15px;" value=""> Wszystkie </option>
                                           <?php foreach ( $wynikiQS1 as $wynikQS ) {
                                            if (($_POST['priorytet']) == $wynikQS) echo '<option value="'.$wynikQS.'" class="filterItem" selected>'.$wynikQS.'</option>';
                                            else echo '<option value="'.$wynikQS.'" class="filterItem">'.$wynikQS.'</option>';
                                        }?>
                                    </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="large-18 small-9 columns">
                                <label class="filter-title" for="filter_Program">Działanie</label>
                                <?php 
                                    $wynikiQS2 = get_custom('wnioski_dzialania');
                                    $wynikiQS2 = explode('|',$wynikiQS2);
                                    ?>
                                    <select class="help MIRFiszkaFiltryProgram"  onchange="this.form.submit();" id="filter_Program" name="dzialanie">
                                        <option style="padding-left:15px;" value=""> Wszystkie </option>
                                             <?php foreach ( $wynikiQS2 as $wynikQS ) {
                                            if (($_POST['dzialanie']) == $wynikQS) echo '<option value="'.$wynikQS.'" class="filterItem" selected>'.$wynikQS.'</option>';
                                            else echo '<option value="'.$wynikQS.'" class="filterItem">'.$wynikQS.'</option>';
                                        }?>
                                    </select>
                            </div>
            </div>
```

Generating `$wynik`:

```
///////////////// temat       

                                if (!empty($_POST['temat'])) { 
                                    $temat = trim($_POST['temat']); // usuwamy spację z początku i końca, żeby działało zapytanie!!!!
                                    $resultsT = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = "temat" AND meta_value = "'.$temat.'"', OBJECT );
                                    if (!empty($resultsT))
                                    {
                                        $i = 0;
                                        foreach ( $resultsT as $result ) {$wynikQ[$i] = $result->post_id; $i++;}
                                        $wynik2 = $wynikQ;  //szukanie elementów wspolnych dla wojewodztwa i wynik/ogloszenie
                                    }
                                    else $wynik2 = array(); 
                                }
                                else $wynik2 = $wynikr; //podstawianie pełnej tabiicy jesli nie ma wynikow wyszukiwania




                            ///////////////// dzialanie   

                                if (!empty($_POST['dzialanie'])) { //sprawdzanie wojewodztwa
                                $dzialanie = trim($_POST['dzialanie']);
                                        $resultsD = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = "dziaania" AND meta_value = "'.$dzialanie.'"', OBJECT );
                                        if (!empty($resultsD))
                                        {
                                        $i = 0;
                                        foreach ( $resultsD as $result ) {$wynikQ[$i] = $result->post_id; $i++;}
                                        $wynik3 = $wynikQ;  //szukanie elementów wspolnych dla wojewodztwa i wynik/ogloszenie
                                        }
                                        else $wynik3 = array(); 
                                     }  
                                else $wynik3 = $wynikr; //podstawianie pełnej tabiicy jesli nie ma wynikow wyszukiwania



                            ////////////////// priorytet
                                if (!empty($_POST['priorytet'])) { //sprawdzanie wojewodztwa
                                $priorytet = trim($_POST['priorytet']);
                                    $resultsP = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = "priorytet" AND meta_value = "'.$priorytet.'"', OBJECT );
                                    if (!empty($resultsP))
                                    {
                                        $i = 0;
                                        foreach ( $resultsP as $result ) {$wynikQ[$i] = $result->post_id; $i++;}
                                        $wynik1 = $wynikQ; //szukanie elementów wspolnych dla wojewodztwa i wynik/ogloszenie
                                    }
                                   else $wynik1 = array();

                                }  
                                else $wynik1 = $wynikr; //podstawianie pełnej tabiicy jesli nie ma wynikow wyszukiwania

$wynik = array_intersect($wynikr,$wynik1, $wynik2, $wynik3, $wynik4, $wynik5, $wynik6, $wynikData);
```

And query:

```
if (!empty($wynik))
                                   {
                                   $args = array('post_type' => 'post', 'post__in' => $wynik, 'cat' => 10,'paged'   => $paged);
                                   $the_query=new WP_Query( $args );
                                   $data=serialize($the_query); 
                                   $encoded=htmlentities($data);
                                        if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
                                            <section class="large-12 columns applications-content" aria-relevant="all" aria-atomic="true" aria-live="assertive">
                                                <div id="inp">
                                                    <h2 class="filter-headline">      
                                                        Dostępne <b><?php echo $the_query->found_posts;?> ogłoszeń naborów wniosków</b> ze wszystkich kategorii<br>
                                                    </h2>
                                                    <ul id="applications-list">
                                                        <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
                                                        <?php $meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID() ); 
                                                        //print_r($meta);
                                                        $program = $meta['program'][0];
                                                        $dzialanie = $meta['dzialanie'][0];
                                                        $url = get_the_permalink();
                                                        $dataOD = $meta['termin_naboru_wniosku_rozpoczcie'][0];
                                                        $dataDO = $meta['termin_naboru_wniosku_zakoczenie'][0];
                                                        ?>
                                                        <!-- Właściwe wyniki wyszukiwania -->
                                                        <li class="row">
                                                            <div class="large-18 columns">
                                                                <div onclick="<?php echo $url;?>';" style="border-color: #d60582" class="info">
                                                                    <div>
                                                                        <?php $nr_p = explode(' ',$program);
                                                                            echo $program;
                                                                        ?>
                                                                        <strong class="small">
                                                                            <?php $nr_d = explode(' ',$dzialanie);
                                                                            echo $nr_d[0];
                                                                            ?>
                                                                        </strong>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                 </div>
                                                                 <div class="right-info">
                                                                    <a class="title" href="<?php echo $url;?>"><?php echo get_the_title();?></a>
                                                                    <p>
                                                                        <span class="status">
                                                                            <?php
                                                                            if ($dataOD > $today) $status = 'Planowany';
                                                                            if ($dataDO < $today) $status = 'Zakończony';
                                                                            if (($dataOD <= $today) && ($dataDO >= $today)) $status = 'Aktualny';
                                                                            echo $status;    ?>
                                                                        </span>
                                                                        <span aria-label="Data naboru wniosków" class="date">
                                                                            <i class="icon ico-blackclock"></i>
                                                                            <span>od</span>
                                                                            <span> <?php echo $dataOD;?></span>
                                                                            <span>do</span>
                                                                            <span> <?php echo $dataDO;?></span>
                                                                        </span>
                                                                    </p>
                                                                 </div>
                                                             </div>  
                                                         </li>      
                                                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                                                     </ul>
                                                    <ul class="pager pagenav">
                                                        <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
                                                    </ul>
                                                    </div> <!-- #inp -->
                                                    </section>
                                                    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Any help would be great, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array('post_type' => 'post', 
              'post__in'  => $wynik, 
              'cat'       => 10,
              'paged'     => $paged
             );
 $the_query=new WP_Query( $args );
```

try this one.

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
```

this is important part may be you are missed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunetalyy this doesn't help. Still, when I'm using filters paginations uses full query. Other ideas?

Comment: Ok, I think that the problem is because when I click for example link to second page, my `$_POST` variable arent't posted. And filter is reseting. But how can I remeber this variables? I cannot use get instead of post.

Comment: you have to edit pagination link ... you have to sent $_get data again with same link on pagination

Comment: ok, thank you for this suggestion, but when I'm using $_GET I have another problem. First of all when in $_get data I have polish signs, like 'ł', 'ą' etc. I get error 500. Any idea why maybe? And second, list of posts is displayed correctly but even if I have only two posts for example, pagination is still showing, and second page (after i click on a link in pagination) is empty (because we have only two posts, which were displayed on the first page).

Comment: Its not going to like that.. 

pagination is based on post count.. post lase page is not possible in pagination... something is going wrong with your pagination for this issue ..

Comment: and for other issue you have to give your code access to expert ... your problem is can not understandable with this description you provide.

Comment: Did you check it.

>https://wordpress.org/support/topic/pagination-a-filter-result